# What is the probability density function of (2X−1)Y?

Tags: probability

The probability density function of a random variable X is the exponential distribution of parameter $\frac{1}{2}$ . The probability density function of a random variable Y is a standard normal distribution. X and Y are independent of each other.

What is the probability density function of $Z=(2X−1)Y$ ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried a change of variable $(z,t)=((2X-1)Y, 2X-1)$ but I don't have a converging integral when I try to calculate .

Comment: You could find the density of $W:=2X-1$ and then use the product density formula:
$$
f_Z(z) = \int_{\mathbb R}f_W(w)f_Y(z/w)\frac1{|w|}\ \mathsf dw,
$$
although that integral may be difficult to compute.

Comment: I tried this but I have a problem finding an integral that converges.What result should this formula give ?